# read a file from Server path - bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am passing a file full path like `/tmp/user/abc.txt` to a shell script where I want to read the file and store its content in a variable.

right now am using the following:

```
export SUBJECT=`echo ${1}`

SUBJECT_1=`cat $SUBJECT`
```

This is not printing anything. Additionally , the content of this file will have some Japanese characters as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your code:

1. You have a missing backquote here `SUBJECT_1=cat $SUBJECT``.
2. `export SUBJECT=echo ${1}` is a false statement. It should be `export SUBJECT="${1}"`.
3. Backquotes execute the code inside them in a subshell, so it will not print your file's content. If you want to print it you will have to add this line: `echo "${SUBJECT_1}"`.

Once you fix these the code will work, but here are a few tips you should consider:

1. You should use `$(code)` if you want to execute code in a subshell instead of using backquotes, you can read about it in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts).
2. Next time when you're stuck on shell code try [this](http://www.shellcheck.net/) first, it has great debugging capabilities for shell code and you can find the command line version of it.
3. Always use double quotes on variables, it keeps the variable from splitting. You can read about it [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html).

Comment: HI Samy, I tried your suggestion still printing nothing actually,

Comment: HI Samy, I tried your suggestion still printing nothing actually, Let me explain the issue more clearly   in Shell Script the is a variable `SUBJECT` if do `echo $SUBJECT` I get `/usr/tmp/abc.txt` when I do `echo $(cat /usr/tmp/abc.txt)` in shell script , its not printing anything, but if I do `cat /usr/tmp/abc.txt` in the terminal , its printing the value. All I need to do is to get the value of `abc.txt` which is in SUBJECT ie `usr/tmp/abc.txt` in another variable

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and paste your entire script for clarity? Also, add two sections: Expected output and Actual output.

Comment: thanks.. that's resolved , issue was there was a space between = symbol and backtick :)